# How to select prev no to related element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

I would like to slide divs, all of them will have same id because they'll generate inside loop so also trigger has same id. That's why I want  to use one function, at the moment function works only for first div and I have no idea how to fix it. I would like that each button would work for div above him.

html part

```
<div id='slide'>
hello
</div>
<p id='but'>click</p>

<div id='slide'>
hello
</div>
<p id='but'>click</p>
```

and the js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(this).click(function(){
    $("#slide").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem is that you have duplicate IDs on the same page. This is invalid markup. Please consider using classes instead.

Comment: use `$(".slide").slideToggle("slow");` and `<div class="slide">`

Comment: See [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme) on why you can't have duplicate IDs.

Comment: but if I would do like that then one button will slide all divs and I want one button work on one div, any other solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't have same `id`s on one page - use `class`es instead. If you want to do something with the element before clicked item, you can use `prev()`, something like this (in your code just change `css('color', 'red')` to `slideToggle("slow")`, I have added it just for example):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".but").click(function() {
    $(this).prev().css('color', 'red');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='slide'>
  hello
</div>
<p class='but'>click</p>

<div class='slide'>
  hello
</div>
<p class='but'>click</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Few issues:

Use classes not IDs and use the ID of the click element `#but` instead of `this` for your click function

```
<div class='slide'>
hello
</div>
<p class='but'>click</p>

<div class='slide'>
hello
</div>
<p class='but'>click</p>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.but).click(function(){
       $(".slide").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: you say _Use classes not IDs_... the reason is so the `ids` don't duplicate, yet you have two `id="but"`.